# Java core application sending Application Insights data (logs) to azure portal when debugging and not on normal application run

Tags: java, azure, logging, log4j, azure-application-insights

I have a java application(not web) that periodically logs data on the file system as well as console.  The application is built in Java and is using log4j-1.2.17.jar for logging.

I have configured the java application to send log data to application insights resource of Azure.

The configuration involved adding applicationinsights-core-2.6.1.jar and applicationinsights-logging-log4j1_2-2.6.1.jar to build path of the java project.
When I execute the code in Debug mode, the application sends the log data to azure portal.

When I execute the code in non debug mode, the application fails to send the log data to azure portal.
Can someone please let me know what i am missing so that the application starts sending data to portal in normal mode(non debug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/console)

> Telemetry is not sent instantly. Telemetry items are batched and sent
> by the ApplicationInsights SDK. In Console apps, which exits right
> after calling Track() methods, telemetry may not be sent unless
> Flush() and Sleep/Delay is done before the app exits as shown in full
> example later in this article.

You can add a flush() and sleep() method to have a try.It can be your application is over,but telemetry haven't sent.

Hope this can help you.